# word wrap/break in FF help?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am building new site FF and IE compliant...what is best way to have sentences wrap to fill container in firefox?
This works in IE without any problem.

Currently I am using the following doctype
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

thanks

Comment: Set a width ? Do you have any screenshots or links ?

Comment: Don't they do this by default?

Comment: Can you please be more specific when you say "sentences wrap to fill container?"  Every browser I know of already does word wrap if that's what you mean...

Comment: What type of element is the 'container'?  Could you provide a small code sample of it and the sentence within?

Comment: I have code like this
<table><tr><td>
<div class="articleContent" >
     <asp:Literal ID="litArticle" runat="server" />
</div>
</td></tr></table>
When from code behind, I add litArticle.Text = "this is a long sentence that goes on and on.  This is a long sentence that goes on and on. "

Comment: The output from this shows 1 line height about 400 px wide.  I was looking for it to be 200px wide with multiple lines (css articleContent has width:200px)

Comment: try building a test case with pure html. If it behaves different, then its an asp issue, not html.

Comment: You should post your CSS.  That's probably where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried a test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.articleContent { width:200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table><tr><td> <div class="articleContent" > this is a sentence that goes on and on. this is a sentence that goes on and on. this is a sentence that goes on and on. this is a sentence that goes on and on. this is a sentence that goes on and on. </div> </td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Renders fine in FF/konq. Sounds like your CSS is getting overridden somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your CSS

```
#container {overflow: auto;}
```

Or

```
#container {overflow: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may mean something along the lines

```
div.mydiv {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I don't think there is anything controlling breaks between words: they always occur as necessary.